# Prevent TextView from wrapping long text

Tags: android, textview

Each row of my `WearableRecyclerView` has a `TextView`.  The contents of the `TextViews` can vary in length, however, whenever the length of the text is long and needs to break, it is breaking incorrectly.

It makes more sense visually:

[image]
[image]

As you can see there is plenty of room on the first line but it's breaking early.

I don't know if it's the text itself.  If I hardcode in the text, instead of setting it dynamically, it looks fine:

[image]

My row item code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/episode_row_item_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/episode_row_item_thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/episode_row_item_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/episode_row_item_thumbnail"
                android:lines="2"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/episode_row_item_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/episode_row_item_title"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/episode_row_item_thumbnail"
                />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

In the `Adapter` I'm just setting the `TextView's` text in `onBindViewHolder` via the `setText` method.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after posting this, I immediately found the answer.  Adding this fixed it:

```
android:breakStrategy="simple"
```